# Importing cross-table in R

Tags: r, long-integer

I am trying to import a cross table into R to work with. The table looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(`0` = c(.1, .2, .3),  
`15` = c(70, 70, 71), 
`30` = c(71, 72, 75))
```

Or:

```
0    15   30
.1   70   71
.2   70   72
.3   71   75
```

What I want is to write a piece of code to translate this into the following format:

```
df_transformed <- data.frame(x = c(15, 15, 15, 30, 30, 30), y = c(.1, .2, .3, .1, .2, .3), z = c(70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 75)
```

Or:

```
x   y   z
15  .1  70
15  .2  70
15  .3  71
30  .1  71
30  .2  72
30  .3  75
```

This way the `df_transformed` will describe every possible combination with attached value as if you would look it up in a cross table (`df`). I.e.: If the column of `df` is equal to `15` and the row is equal to `.1`, then the corresponding value is `70`. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried `tidyr::gather()`, but it fails to describe every unique `z` value.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, from what do you import? Your code for `df` doesn't work, please fix that.

Comment: I will try to explain. It is a table from Excel where you can look up a value based on the horizontal and vertical input. Much like this: https://datamgmt.ucsc.edu/images/infoview/how-do-i/formatting/cross-tab/cross-tab-image1.jpg. In this example the corresponding value for "Arts Division" and "F" is "9086". Does that make sense? I will adapt the code for `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `stack`

```
dfout <- setNames(cbind(df[1],stack(df[-1])),u <-c("y","z","x"))[order(u)]
```

such that

```
> dfout
    x   y  z
1 X15 0.1 70
2 X15 0.2 70
3 X15 0.3 71
4 X30 0.1 71
5 X30 0.2 72
6 X30 0.3 75
```

Comment: This works like a charm and it is easy and compact code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outer` to apply a `Vectorized` `FUN`ction on all permutations of rows and columns,

```
FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) df[x, y + 1])
res <- data.frame(x=colnames(m), y=rownames(m), 
                  z=as.vector(outer(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m), FUN)),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
res
#     x   y  z
# 1 X15 0.1 70
# 2 X30 0.2 70
# 3 X15 0.3 71
# 4 X30 0.1 71
# 5 X15 0.2 72
# 6 X30 0.3 75
```

where:

```
sapply(res, class)
#           x           y           z 
# "character" "character"   "numeric"
```

If you want x and y to be clean numeric, do:

```
res <- transform(res, 
          x=as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)),
          y=as.numeric(y)
          )
#    x   y  z
# 1 15 0.1 70
# 2 30 0.2 70
# 3 15 0.3 71
# 4 30 0.1 71
# 5 15 0.2 72
# 6 30 0.3 75
```

**More generally**, to break down a matrix `m`

```
      C1    C2    C3   C4
R1  9086  9220 11985  469
R2  5627  6463  5447  258
R3  6561  1632  1773   72
R4 12468 12555 13409 1148
R5 21886 28320 22227 2502
R6 23231 22127 23402 3242
```

into its row and column coordinates we may do:

```
fun <- Vectorize(function(x, y) m[x, y])
res <- cbind(rownames(m), colnames(m), as.vector(outer(1:6, 1:4, fun)))

res
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]   
#  [1,] "R1" "C1" "9086" 
#  [2,] "R2" "C2" "5627" 
#  [3,] "R3" "C3" "6561" 
#  [4,] "R4" "C4" "12468"
#  [5,] "R5" "C1" "21886"
#  [6,] "R6" "C2" "23231"
#  [7,] "R1" "C3" "9220" 
#  [8,] "R2" "C4" "6463" 
#  [9,] "R3" "C1" "1632" 
# [10,] "R4" "C2" "12555"
# [11,] "R5" "C3" "28320"
# [12,] "R6" "C4" "22127"
# [13,] "R1" "C1" "11985"
# [14,] "R2" "C2" "5447" 
# [15,] "R3" "C3" "1773" 
# [16,] "R4" "C4" "13409"
# [17,] "R5" "C1" "22227"
# [18,] "R6" "C2" "23402"
# [19,] "R1" "C3" "469"  
# [20,] "R2" "C4" "258"  
# [21,] "R3" "C1" "72"   
# [22,] "R4" "C2" "1148" 
# [23,] "R5" "C3" "2502" 
# [24,] "R6" "C4" "3242"
```

---

*Data*

```
m <- structure(c(9086, 5627, 6561, 12468, 21886, 23231, 9220, 6463, 
1632, 12555, 28320, 22127, 11985, 5447, 1773, 13409, 22227, 23402, 
469, 258, 72, 1148, 2502, 3242), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6"), c("C1", "C2", "C3", 
    "C4")))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(X15, X30), names_to = c("x"), values_to = "z", names_pattern = "X(\\d+)", names_ptypes = list(x = numeric())) %>%
  rename(y = X0) %>%
  arrange(x, y) %>%
  select(x, y, z)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    15   0.1    70
2    15   0.2    70
3    15   0.3    71
4    30   0.1    71
5    30   0.2    72
6    30   0.3    75
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gather()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = "15", value = "30", -`0`) %>%
  select(x = `15`, y = `0`, z = `30`) %>%
  arrange(x, y)
```

`gather()` probably wasn't working because of its tricky argument specification. That's one reason why `pivot_longer()` was invented.

I know there's a `pivot_longer()` answer above that takes advantage of all of the function's special arguments, but this is probably a more understandable and equally effective implementation in your case:

```
df_transformed <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`0`, names_to = "15", values_to = "30") %>%
  select(x = `15`, y = `0`, z = `30`) %>%
  arrange(x, y)
```